# Convert timedelta to milliseconds python

Tags: python, timestamp, timedelta

I have the following time:

```py
time = datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=4, minutes=5, seconds=33, milliseconds=623)
```

Is it possible, to convert the time in milliseconds? 
Like this:

```py
101133623.0
```

Comment: that's not a timestamp, that's a duration, see [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). If your data type is already `timedelta`, the conversion is as simple as `.total_seconds() * 1e3`.

Comment: yeah thank's i already solved the problem with this function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a possibility to solve the problem

```py
import datetime

time = datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=4, minutes=5, seconds=33, milliseconds=623)
result = time.total_seconds()*1000
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), the recommended way to convert a timedelta to milliseconds is:

`millis = td / timedelta(milliseconds=1)`

I'm not sure what if any different results that will give compared to the `total_seconds() * 1000` solution that you have shared.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible.

```
1 day + 4 hours + 5 minutes + 33 seconds + 623 milliseconds =
24 * 60 * 60 seconds + 4 * 60 * 60 seconds + 5 * 60 seconds + 33 seconds + 0.623 seconds =
86400 seconds + 14400 seconds + 300 seconds + 33 seconds + 0.623 seconds =
101133.623 seconds
```

Just use multiplication

Function Below:

```
def timestamp_to_milliseconds(timestamp):

  day, hour, minute, second, millisecond = timestamp.split(":")
  seconds = int(day) * 24 * 60 * 60 + int(hour) * 60 * 60 + int(minute) * 60 + int(second)
  seconds += float(millisecond) / 1000
  milliseconds = seconds * 1000

  return milliseconds
```

Comment: is there a other possibility to calc the ms?

Comment: I have added a function to make it easier for you.

Comment: unfortunately it doen't works because timestamp is not a str. Also Converting to str doesn't work. I thought python had a method for calculating. Thank you anyway